# Two segues from similar UIVIewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm trying to work with tho segues with similar source and different destinations. Both segues connect two UIViewControllers. I want them to be called by pushing the Button depending on choosed task. There is the code of this button. But when i run code it reports the error "SIGABRT". There are no mistakes in identifiers.

```
-(void) goTarget
    {if (_spaseType==0) {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromWelkomeToPlanemetry"  sender:self];
    }else{
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromWelcomeToStereometry" sender:self];
}}
```

*the stack trace*

```
(
0   secondTry_GeometryHelper            0x000000010e8d705f -[DTStartVC goTarget] + 63
1   UIKit                               0x000000010ebcca22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
2   UIKit                               0x000000010ecd3e50 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
3   UIKit                               0x000000010ecd2ddf -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 224
4   UIKit                               0x000000010ec129ce -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 325
5   UIKit                               0x000000010ec13493 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
6   UIKit                               0x000000010ebdffb1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
7   UIKit                               0x000000010ebed227 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17700
8   UIKit                               0x000000010ebc823c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105cfc91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105c5b5d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105c5194 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105c4bc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
13  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112ceaa58 GSEventRunModal + 161
14  UIKit                               0x000000010ebcb580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
15  secondTry_GeometryHelper            0x000000010e8d19a3 main + 115
16  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110ce5145 start + 1
17  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

)

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: set a breakpoint in goTarget and check for _splashType value

Comment: Did you mean _spaceType value? it is OK

Comment: In your code above you've used "_spaseType". Could this be a confusion between that and "_spaceType"?

Comment: No. I've used brakepoints. Error reports after [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromWelkomeToPlenemetry" sender:self]; the same with "else" code